# interpolate.griddata shifts data northwards, is it a bug?

Tags: python, scipy, geospatial, matplotlib-basemap, imshow

I observe unexpected results from `scipy.interpolate.griddata`. I am trying to visualize a set of irregularly spaced points using `matplotlib.basemap` and `scipy.interpolate.griddata`.

The data is given as three lists: latitudes, longitudes and values. To get them on the map I interpolate the data onto a regular grid and visualize it using Basemap's `imshow` function.

I observe that the interpolated data is shifted northwards from true positions.

Here is an example. Here I want to highlight a cell formed by two meridians and two parallels. I expect to get something like this:

[image: expected image]

However what I get is something like this:

[image: observed image]

You can see that the red rectangle is visibly shifted northwards.

I have tried to vary the grid resolution and the number of points, however this does not seem to have any effect on this observed shift.

Here is an [IPython notebook](https://gist.github.com/d1mach/6bbe5c5351f32c5ac74e4dfa8e42b356) that illustrates the issue.

Also below is the complete code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

# defining the region of interest
r = {'lon':[83.0, 95.5], 'lat':[48.5,55.5]}
# initializing Basemap
m = Basemap(projection='merc', 
            llcrnrlon=r['lon'][0],
            llcrnrlat=r['lat'][0],
            urcrnrlon=r['lon'][1],
            urcrnrlat=r['lat'][1],
            lon_0=r['lon'][0], 
            ellps='WGS84',
            fix_aspect=True,
            resolution='h')
# defining the highlighted block
block = {'lon':[89,91],'lat':[50.5,52.5]}
# generating the data
npixels = 100000
lat_range = r['lat'][1] - r['lat'][0]
lats = lat_range * random.random(npixels) + r['lat'][0]
lon_range = r['lon'][1] - r['lon'][0]
lons = lon_range * random.random(npixels) + r['lon'][0]
values = np.zeros(npixels)
for p in range(npixels):
    if block['lat'][0] < lats[p] < block['lat'][1] \
    and block['lon'][0] < lons[p] < block['lon'][1]:
        values[p] = 1.0 
# plotting the original data without interpolation
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
m.drawparallels(np.arange(r['lat'][0], r['lat'][1] + 0.25, 2.0),
                    labels=[True,False,True,False])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(r['lon'][0], r['lon'][1] + 0.25, 2.0), 
                    labels=[True,True,False,True])
m.scatter(lons,lats,c=values,latlon=True,edgecolors='none')
# interpolating on the regular grid
nx = ny = 500
mapx = np.linspace(r['lon'][0],r['lon'][1],nx)
mapy = np.linspace(r['lat'][0],r['lat'][1],ny)
mapgridx,mapgridy = np.meshgrid(mapx,mapy)
mapdata = interpolate.griddata(list(zip(lons,lats)),values,
                   (mapgridx,mapgridy),method='nearest')
# plotting the interpolated data
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
m.drawparallels(np.arange(r['lat'][0], r['lat'][1] + 0.25, 2.0),
                    labels=[True,False,True,False])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(r['lon'][0], r['lon'][1] + 0.25, 2.0), 
                    labels=[True,True,False,True])
m.imshow(mapdata)
```

I am seeing this with SciPy 0.17.0

Answer (score 0):

Pauli Virtanen on SciPy bugtracker [answered the question](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6752).

The issue goes away if one replaces `basemap.imshow()` with `matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh()`

Replacing above

```
m.imshow(mapdata)
```

with

```
meshx,meshy = m(mapx,mapy)
plt.pcolormesh(meshx,meshy,mapdata)
```

produces correctly aligned image.

[image]

It is not clear what I am doing wrong with `basemap.imshow`, but that is probably another question.